# PHP - Checking values against database before inserting

Tags: php, ms-access-2010

I am writing a script where data is being pulled from a file, checked against the number of characters for the "msubject" field and then being put on the screen. After that, I am trying to insert the values that are on the screen to the database, but before doing that, I need to check if that row already exists. The problem I am having is checking against a couple of values and if they do really exist to not put it in the database. Currently if true or false, the data is still being put in the database. I am not using mysql, I am using msaccess as my db. Unfortunately that is the only db I can use. Below is the code I am using. Would you know why if true or false, the data is being put into the db?

```
<?php
$dbco = realpath('C:\xampp\htdocs\db.accdb');
$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$dbco",'','') or die ("Unable to connect to server");

$query = "SELECT * FROM CriticalMeetings";
$result = odbc_exec ($conn, $query);
$filename = "test.tsv";
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$file = file($filename);

foreach($file as $line)
{
    list($start_datetime, $end_datetime, $organizer, $msubject)= explode("\t", $line);
    $count = mb_strlen($msubject);
    if ($count > 79)
    {

    //Start Date-Time split
    $StartDatetime = new DateTime($start_datetime);
    $start_date = $StartDatetime->format('Y-m-d');
    $start_time = $StartDatetime->format('H:i:s');

    //End Date-Time split
    $EndDatetime = new DateTime($end_datetime);
    $End_date = $EndDatetime->format('Y-m-d');
    $End_time = $EndDatetime->format('H:i:s');

        if ($start_date = $today)
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$start_date</td>";
        echo "<td>$start_time</td>";
        echo "<td>$organizer</td>";
        echo "<td>$msubject</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $db_start_date = ($row["StartDate"]);
        $db_start_time = ($row["StartTime"]);
        $db_organizer = ($row["Organizer"]);
        $db_MeetingSubject = ($row["MeetingSubject"]);
        echo "<br />";
        echo "$db_organizer";

        if ($organizer == $db_organizer)
        {
        //Replace apostrophe    
        $msubject = str_replace( "'", "&#39;", $msubject);
        //Insert values into db
        $input="INSERT INTO CriticalMeetings (StartDate, StartTime, Organizer, MeetingSubject)
        VALUES ('$start_date', '$start_time', '$organizer', '$msubject')";
        $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$input);
        if (!$rs)
            {
            die('Error: ' . odbc_error());
            }
        }
        else
        {
        echo "data not in db";
        }   

    } 

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: "I am having is checking against a couple of values and if they do really exist to not put it in the database" - Which values are you checking against?

Comment: @OzairKafray - I am checking against the start_date, start_time, organizer, and msubject. For the purpose of testing, I just was trying if ($organizer == $db_organizer).

Comment: Can you paste a sample line from the file you are reading in the question. That would help in debugging. HINT: If you want strict checking between variables you should check like this: `$organizer === $db_organizer` If that works for you I will explain in detail in an answer.

Comment: @OzairKafray - having triple equal signs did not work

Comment: Please add a sample line from the file you are reading in the question.